# Display date in MM-dd-yyyy format SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SQL query: `select ModifiedDate from Person.Person` and this returns the date as `2/24/1998 12:00:00 AM`

I'm trying to display this in `MM/dd/yyyy` format in SSRS report. I have used the expression `=Format(Fields!ModifiedDate.Value,"MM/dd/yyyy")`

But, still it's coming as `2/24/1998 12:00:00 AM`

I want to display this as `2/24/1998`.

How can I do this?

Comment: so you'r asking to set date in **MM-dd-yyyy** format. then why you are trying to format it as **MM/dd/yyyy** ?

Answer (score 23):

I would recommend using the format codes:

Right click - properties on the cell, select format, click the ellipsis "...", and you can see the date formats from there. This will be converted into a date code when you OK the dialog.  This is useful as it sets the date in the fomat the user wants to see it in.

To convert the data within SSRS and not the data source you could try using something like:

```
=Format(Cdate(Fields!ModifiedDate.Value),"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Another sample for you without Cdate:

```
=Format(Fields!ModifiedDate.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: what is SSS if you could elaborate would be helpful

Comment: It was just an erroneous fieldname, i'll edit it to be clearer.

Answer (score 10):

There is a special function for formatting Dates in SSRS:

```
=FormatDateTime(Fields!ModifiedDate.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

It will return your date the way that you want it.

Answer (score 6):

As per your question,

To convert the date in SSRS you should try like this,

```
=FORMAT(Fields!ModifiedDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Output would be,

```
12-06-2010 -- 12(Month)-06(Date)-2010(Year)
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the language of the entire Report to the language of the country the report is going to be run in.

For example for US it's en_US and for Australia it's en_AU.

Simple !

Comment: I don't see why this would make SSRS switch from General Date to Short Date. [Edit] to explain?

Comment: I believe this is useful as it addresses the issue of US vs English date format. Simply changing the report language would mean that he can use the .net date format 'd' on the date field.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get date in format of 'MM/DD/YYYY' use the following query andand you have to convert in varchar datatype.

```
select CONVERT(varchar(20),GETDATE(),101)
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer add a bit of explanation would help those not just looking for an answer but trying to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and i solve that by this code :

```
FormatDateTime('MM/dd/yyyy',ADOqueryname.fieldbyname('ModifiedDate').AsDateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

I did two things to make it work:

1st, In Data set property Query - `select CONVERT(varchar(20),ModifiedDate,101) from Person.Person`

2nd, In expression - `=Format(Fields!ModifiedDate.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy")`

This worked for me.Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
- FormatDateTime(Fields!ModifiedDate.Value, 2)
```

or:

```
- FormatDateTime(Fields!ModifiedDate.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

You will get the same result.