# Convert DDMMYYYY varchar value to MM-dd-yyyy in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression, ssrs-2014

I wanted to convert `DDMMYYYY` formated data (data type is **varchar**) to `MM-dd-yyyy` format using **SSRS expression** only.

I tried the following but it is showing **#Error**

```
=IIF(NOT(IsNothing(Fields!DoB.Value)),CDate(Fields!DoB.Value).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),Nothing)

=IIF(NOT(IsNothing(Fields!DoB.Value)),Format(CDate(Fields!DoB.Value),"MM-dd-yyyy"),Nothing)
```

It I try like below then it shows `MM-dd-yyyy`,

```
=Format(Fields!DoB.Value, "MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: It would appear that you have already answered this question yourself.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842365/display-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy-format-ssrs-report

Comment: @BIDeveloper - yes I have given answer. but here requirement is different. can you please read my question properly. DDMMYYYY having varchar type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you pass it as a string in your report. Anyway here it is.

I tested it using this expression:

```
= Mid("25052016",3,2)  + "-" + Left("25052016",2) + "-" + Right("25052016", 4)
```

and this is my output:

```
05-25-2016
```

- Basically what I did here is just separate your string in three chunks separated with - to achieve your goal.

So in your example expression you could try it like this:

```
=IIF(NOT(IsNothing(Fields!DoB.Value)),(Mid(Fields!DoB.Value,3,2)  + "-" + Left(Fields!DoB.Value,2) + "-" + Right(Fields!DoB.Value, 4)),Nothing)
```

**Note:** I'm not 100% sure that the expression just above this comment will work in your end because I haven't tested it but atleast I showed to you my concept on my other example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to parse the field value, like this?

```
=Format(CDate(Mid(Fields!DoB.Value,3,2) & "-" & Left(Fields!DoB.Value,2) & "-" & Right(Fields!DoB.Value,4)), "MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: there is an unnecessary quote in your right expression.